# How to modify the words in a sentence efficiently using database?

Tags: mongodb, performance, elasticsearch, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 700K words data which I saved in mongodb in a format like :

```
[{
    "_id":"1",
    "word":"janji",
    "malay_word":" janji",
    "english_word":"promise",
    "word_count":1
},{
    "_id":"2",
    "word":"kena",
    "malay_word":"kena",
    "english_word":"hit",
    "word_count":1
},{
    "_id":"3",
    "word":"love",
    "malay_word":"cinta",
    "english_word":"love",
    "word_count":1
},{
    "_id":"4",
    "word":"love you",
    "malay_word":"cinta kamu",
    "english_word":"love you",
    "word_count":2
}]
```

So what I am doing to convert the sentence from one language to another,

`sentence = "kena love you"`

Step 1 : split the sentence
`sentence = sentence.split(" ")`

Step 2 : generate regular expressions for every word

```
regular_expressions_list = []
for(let i=0;i < sentence.length;i++) {
 regular_expressions_list.push("/^" + sentence[i] + "\b((?!-).)*$/")
}
```

Step 3: search from mongo

```
 db.collectionName.find({"word" : {$in : regular_expressions_list }}).sort({"word_count" : 1})
```

Step 4 : replace the words from data I get from mongodb (**Note** : I have to start replacing the words from the higher word count [ word_count is word field length ])

**Problem:**
So the problem I am facing, when I search large text around (100 words) from mongodb, I get more than 5000 documents which actually reduced the performance of my app. Can anyone suggest what should I do in this or any best approach? or Do I need to use elastic search here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I got after done some testing on different approaches, using n-grams is a better approach. So in my example above :

`sentence = "kena love you"`

1. Added mongo indexing in `word` field
2. Created all possible n-grams (up to 7-grams)

`n_grams = ["kena" ,"love", "you", "kena love", "love you", "kena love you"]`

3. then process from mongodb

`db.collectionName.find({"word" : {$in : n_grams }}).sort({"word_count" : 1})`

The results are very fast with no issues even for large paragraphs, it takes very less time.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

You should use in-memory key-value database, like Redis, as an intermediate layer, instead of using file system based databases.
Every time your application is started, it reads all your tables and records from Mango into Redis, and then you query your words from Redis. Once you updated your Mango DB you can just restart your application to refresh the in-memory database.

Answer (score 1):

100 words is not that big in my opinion. Best thing you can do is to leave regex aside and use exact match. Then, create an index for columns named word and word_count. Not using regex and retrieving and sorting with an index will have a huge impact on your performance.

Comment: Hi sorry, I updated my question after reading your answer please check again and if I remove the regex then I will have the only solution to create possible n-grams to find out from the database those can be so many. My word_count can go up to 6 or 7.